# Hibernate: entity relationships and extra table

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm creating rating system for simple web application that allows users to post text, similiar to twitter's wall. I've got two entities:

First one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String login;

    private String hashPassword;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "connectedUser", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Post> userPosts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Second one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String text;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime postDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User connectedUser;
```

And I'm trying to figure out, where/how to add something responsible for rating.  Every single post can be rated once per user (Plus or minus) and total sum of rate should be displayed nearby. It seems simple, I need separate table in database with user_id, post_id, and rate, but how could I do that in Hibernate (Hibernate creates database by itself)? Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: From a functional point of view, it's trivial. If you want your solution to be scalable (to thousands of users writing thousands of posts and rating each others posts), it's not trivial at all. In contrast, it requires a lot of experience and probably a completely different approach. The list of userPosts in the User class could be a problem already.

Comment: @Stefan agree, as well as bidirectional relationships requires additional handling when it comes to binding them to XML/JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need additional table - you need additional Entity.

For storing the user actions related to post:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_post_rate")
public class UserPostRate {

    @OneToMany
    private Post post;
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    private boolean upvote;
    // ...
}
```

It could be just `boolean` value if you have two fixed actions related to the `post`. You can replace it with some integer values, let's say, for example if privileged user can upvode it for `+ n`, or user can upvote it again after some time and etc.

However you still need sum of rated values to be stored somewhere (not to calculate it time after time).

The overall `post` score is not a good place to be stored in the same table when user-post related actions are stored, because you will keep many unnecessary duplicates here (until you'll need to keep track of post score history). You can store it in `Post` entity, because the score of the post is part of its state:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    // skipped

    private long score;
}
```

Every time a user will rate the post, update for the post entity score should be triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the response. First answer is very helpful, but regarding your question - It's post score. Every single post can be rated once per user (Plus or minus) and total sum of rate should be displayed nearby. How to remember which User has rated this post if you only have long rate variable without remembering User? I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Answer is updated, misunderstood a part of the question.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is more than helpful :)